# how to connect informix driver in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, informix

I am trying to use JMeter the first time, In my test I need to connect to `informix DB`.

I set driver as on the picture:
[image]

However, when I run I get error:

```
Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class...
```

I think that may be I need to provide the jar file with the driver somehow. But I do not know how to do it or may be it is another reason for the problem.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ifxjdbc.jar` to JMeter lib folder

You can download from [link](http://www.dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/InformixJdbcDriver.zip) see more in [informix jdbc driver](http://www.dbschema.com/informix-jdbc-driver.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get new Informix JDBC drivers from maven.

**Gradle**

```
compile group: 'com.ibm.informix', name: 'jdbc', version: '4.10.9'
```

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
<version>4.10.9</version>
</dependency>
```